Draw a line between two points (Grappling Hook) - Godot 4 3D
I am working on a grappling/swinging hook system, which I am still trying to fully figure out, but I wanted to draw a line between the grappling gun and the grapple point. I got the majority of the code from this GitHub repo, and started to try and modify it to fit what I needed, but I'm completely stuck on drawing the grappling line. It uses a CSGCylinder3D and adjusts the position, but currently line line goes way past where the actual grappling point is, which is not good (shown in the image below).
I think that the line is twice as long as it should be, but I can't really tell because of the perspective. I've tried adjusting the parameters in every way I can think of, but nothing seems to work, and it usually just sends the line in the wrong direction. I wouldn't be surprised if the solution is something super simple that bounced off my thick skull, but I am lost. I did try looking into alternative nodes, like path3D, but I don't think that is for this purpose. If there is some other better way to do this then let me know.
I also have a link to my GitHub Repo for the project if that helps.
Variables in the code: line_holder is a node3D parent of the grapple_line, which is the CSGCylinder3D
func draw_hook(length):
    line_holder.look_at(grapple_position, Vector3.UP)
    grapple_line.height = length
    grapple_line.position.z = length / -2


Did you find a solution?
